# What Modern Ways (If Any) Does Node Have to "Override" It's Import System?

Tags: node.js, webpack, import

In Node you can make an `importText` function fairly easily, and then use it in another file like so:

```
import importText from 'importText'
const css = await importText('./someFile.css')
// (This isn't technically possible yet, but top-level await is coming someday)
```

By using Webpack or a similar tool, you can also do the same thing, only with a more convenient syntax:

```
import css from './someFile.css';
```

Node *used to* have a way to do the same thing without Webpack, but the API for it, "require extensions", was deprecated (emphasis added):

> Deprecated. In the past, this list has been used to load non-JavaScript modules into Node.js by compiling them on-demand. However, **in practice, there are much better ways to do this**, such as loading modules via some other Node.js program, or compiling them to JavaScript ahead of time.

- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_extensions

My question is: what are the "much better ways"?

They mention "compiling them to JavaScript ahead of time", which I would assume is the Webpack approach. But how would one "load a module via some other Node.js program" ... or solve the problem any other way (the text I quoted implied those two weren't the only options)?

Comment: Are you asking about things like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) which can add arbitrary features by doing source recompilation?

Comment: Yes but no :) Babel would be the "Webpack" or "compiling them to JavaScript ahead of time" approach.  I'm curious about the *other* options.